# But may be you might of heard tell 'bout the price on her head

Tags: expressions, ellipsis, spelling, colloquial-language, dialect

*Well, she ain't no John Wilkes Booth. But may be you might of heard tell 'bout the price on her head.*

This is a quote from QT's movie the Hateful Eight. I am aware that this is not supposed to be a standard English but the passage in bold is even in this respect a little bit weird. Can you tell me why is "of" before "heard", why is the verb "tell" used there?

Comment: Related link: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/could-of-or-could-have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, about the *of*. That's a phonetics thing:

> might have heard → might've heard → might of heard

As for *tell*, the word "someone" is implied beforehand.

Thus, written in more standard English, the entire sentence could read:

> *But maybe you might have heard someone tell about the price on her head*.

Answer (score 7):

It's common in written English, including some literature,  that seeks to represent **colloquial spoken English** to use *would of* instead of *would've*. This usage is at least 80 years old, probably older.

For instance, the book *[The 42nd Parallel](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7101.The_42nd_Parallel)* (published in 1930) by author John Dos Passos contains this line:

> "I would of too if I hadn't gotten sick."

([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=TFlVe4ySsKQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=1919+john+dos+passos&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitoMi12JHNAhVDLVIKHSD5AD8QuwUILjAD#v=onepage&q=%22would%20of%22%20&f=false))

This is not a spelling mistake. This is a deliberate spelling to represent colloquial speech.

Nowadays, many native speakers mistakenly write *would of* instead of *would've* simply because they don't realize that that is the correct way to write the contraction of *would have*.

To *hear tell of* is a usage that goes way back to old English and represents the ellipsis (omission) of such a noun or pronoun as 'people', 'persons', or 'someone' before the bare infinitive *tell*, *say*, *talk*, *speak*.  It is now dialectal or colloquial.

Source: *Oxford English Dictionary* (*OED*).

An example from about 1325:

> King Macolom **hurde telle þerof** in scotlonde.

In modern English this would be *heard tell (there)of*.

From 1746:

> Before it be two days, if they do not send us other orders, they will **hear tell of** our having done something.

Note that the most common preposition used after *tell*, etc is *of*. The writers may  have changed it to *'bout* to avoid repetition.

So the clause is equivalent to

> ...you might've heard [people] tell about the price on her head.

You can also look up *hear tell* in many  dictionaries, such as [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hear-tell).

The legal term *hearsay* comes from this old usage of *hear + people + say*. See [Etymology online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hearsay) and the *OED*.